# How to extract specific String values using regex

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, replaceall

I am a  newbie in regex, I want to extract values between commas but I don't know how.

I have values like this :

```
 [1000, Value_to_extract, 1150370.5]
```

and I used this Technic to simplify it:

```
String val = "[1000, Value_to_extract, 1150370.5]";

String  designation=val.replace("[",    "").replace("]", "").trim();
```

It give's me this result :

```
1000, Value_to_extract, 1150370.5
```

I don't know how to extract only `Value_to_extract`

I tried : `String  designation=val.replace("[",    "").replace("]", "").replaceAll(".*, ,.*", "").trim();`

but i doesn't work .

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Split using a comma with the [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method

Comment: is `Value_to_extract` also a number?

Comment: `String[] values = val.replace("[",    "").replace("]", "").trim().split("\\s*,\\s*") ` and `String Value_to_extract = values[1]`

Comment: Value_to_extract  is a string

Answer (score 2):

```
String input = "[1000, Value_to_extract, 1150370.5]";
String[] parts = input.replaceAll("\\[\\] ", "")   // strip brackets and whitespace
                      .split(",");                 // split on comma into an array

String valueToExtract = parts[1];                  // grab the second entry
```

**Notes:**

You might also be able to use a regex here, q.v. the answer by @Thomas, but a regex will become unwieldy for extracting values from a CSV string of arbitrary length.  So in general, I would prefer splitting here to using a regex.

Comment: You only made a working solution on given sample input string by OP. However you would mind expanding solution to cover all possible cases.

Comment: It could be multiple values to be extracted `[1000, Value_to_extract_1, Value_to_extract_2, ..., 1150370.5]`

Comment: @revo This is the advantage to using split: you end up with a single array of values, so only the index is needed to find the value you want.

Comment: In sample I provided (or any similar ones) - *as I understand* - OP needs all comma separated values but the first and last one - I mean that's not a single index.

Answer (score 0):

someting like this:

```
,[ ]?([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+),
```

### breakdown

```
, // literal ,
[ ]? // 0 or 1 spaces
([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+) // capture a number with or without a dot
, // another litteral ,
```

https://regex101.com/r/oR7nI8/1

Comment: Thank you . @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

```
    String val = "[1000, Value_to_extract, 1150370.5]";

    //you can remove white space by
    String noSpaces = val.trim();
    System.out.println(noSpaces);

    //you can split the string into string[] settting
    //the delimiting regular expression to ", "
    String[] strings = noSpaces.split(", ");
    //the strings[1] will hold the desired string
    System.out.println(strings[1]);

    //in the private case of val, only Value_to_extract contains letters and "_" ,
    //so you can also extract it using
    System.out.println(val.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z_]", ""));
```

If val does not well represent the more general need, you need to define the need more precisely.